# WebStorm all initialized variables throw error expected BEGIN_ARRAY was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I have the following problem:

I have recently started working on another PC with WebStorm 2016.1.3.
The code that was written before that on the previous PC works fine. But writing on this one, screws everything up.

Whatever variable I initialize, I get error:

> com.google.gson.JsonParseException expected BEGIN_ARRAY was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 1217.

Here is debug snapshot:

[image: ERROR]

You can see how the first array is okay, but the rest is just screwed. Really weird problem, and I suspect the IDE. Anyone had that issue?

Comment: From what I see you are debugging this code; those messages look like in-line info from the debugger. You can stop debugging session and start writing your code without them.

Comment: I know, I am just showing it so people can see what is going on

Comment: Well .. if you are using **2016.1.3** then try upgrading to latest stable **2016.3.x** to start with .. maybe even try 2017.1 EAP build. Looks like some debug protocol incompatibility to me (diff version is expected)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the cache of the browser and the IDE. It fixed itself after restart and cache kill.